# jquery ui dialog messed up if HTML is inside

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

So here is my HTML:

```
<a href="#/" class="next openModalBox lessOpacity">Posunúť sa dopredu</a>
<div id="modalBoxContent">
    <p style="font-size: .8em; text-align: center;">
    Úspešne ste absolvovali študijnú časť školenia.
        Pre ukončenie školenia je potrebné úspešne absolvovať <a href="/index/index" class="accessible-link">záverečný test</a>.
</p>
</div>
```

And my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // vytvorenie kurzu
    $('a.openModalBox').click(function(e) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if ('#/' == href) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#modalBoxContent').dialog({
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                title: 'Upozornenie',
                zIndex: 1,
                show: 'fast',
                hide: 'slow',
                width: 600,
                height: 90,
                position: 'middle'
            }).width(600);
        }
    });

});
```

The problem is the dialog window is messed up. This is its HTML:

```
<div style="width: 1920px; height: 862px; z-index: 2;" class="ui-widget-overlay"></div>
<div aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-modalBoxContent" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all  ui-draggable" style="display: block; z-index: 3; outline: 0px none; height: auto; width: 600px; top: 381px; left: 655px;">
<div style="-moz-user-select: none;" unselectable="on" class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
<span style="-moz-user-select: none;" unselectable="on" id="ui-dialog-title-modalBoxContent" class="ui-dialog-title">Upozornenie</span>
<a style="-moz-user-select: none;" unselectable="on" role="button" class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" href="#"><span style="-moz-user-select: none;" unselectable="on" class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span></a>
</div>
<div class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="display: block; width: 600px; min-height: 0px; height: 36px;" id="modalBoxContent">
                    <p style="font-size: 0.8em; text-align: center;">
                        Úspešne ste absolvovali študijnú časť školenia.
Pre ukončenie školenia je potrebné úspešne absolvovať <a href="/index/index" class="accessible-link">záverečný test</a>.
                    </p>

</div></div>
```

It looks like this:

http://i51.tinypic.com/2ai4oro.jpg

When there just a text inside the #modalBoxContent, the dialog window looks as it is supposed to. It looks messed up only when there is some HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have works, [you can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Xcw9E/).  Make sure that you're HTML is valid and there aren't any unclosed/invalid tags, also make sure that your CSS isn't interfering (this is likely the cause).  Try just *not* including your own stylesheet (but still including the jQuery UI one) and see if it resolves the issue.